# Is Θ(log(n!)) = Θ(n log(n))?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

From what I understand saying that if an algorithm is in Θ(log(n!)) then it is in O(n log(n)) is correct, as big-O denotes an upper bound. Would it be also correct to say that if an algorithm is in Θ(log(n!)) then it is in Θ(n log(n))?

By plotting the two growths I can see they are similar but is it correct to say that they are equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  n! < n<sup>n</sup>, so log(n!) < n * log(n).

At the same time, n! > (n/2)<sup>n/2</sup> (for even n), so log(n!) > (n/2) * (log(n)-1)

Comment: I'm sorry if the question wasn't clear. I know that log(n!) < n log(n), as I stated in the question body. I was asking if Θ(log(n!)) = Θ(n log(n)).

Comment: The question was very clear.  The first line shows that O(n!) <= O(n log n).  The second line shows that O(n log n) <= O(n!)

Comment: Why does plotting the two show that log(n!) < n log(n) for every n? Is that irrelevant when referring to big-Theta notation?

Comment: It's relevant to the first part.  You could also plot log(n!) and (n log (n))/3, which would go the other way for all sufficiently large n.  They are the same up to multiplication by a constant, which is what you asked.